# Inverting a transition matrix with small grid size

Tags: linear-algebra, python, scipy

Time is continuous time. I have a 3D state space, and transition rates across all of these.

Using the transition rates, I can compute a *generator* matrix `A` associated with the markov process. My `A` satisfies all requirements on a  generator matrix:

1. `A_ii < 0` and  `A_ij >=0` for all i and j
2. Also, rows sum up to zero.

I want to compute the implied stationary distribution `g` given by

```
dot(A.T,  g) = z
sum(g) = 1
```

where `z` is a zero vector. To ensure the second condition, I set `z_i = 1` for some `i`, `A_ii = 1`, `A_ij = 0` for all `j != i`.

Now, my problem is that I don't always get to invert `A`, despite it satisfying all the conditions for a generator matrix. Python just gives me

```
scipy.sparse.linalg.dsolve.linsolve.MatrixRankWarning: Matrix is exactly singular
```

---

I have a suspect: My grid size. Let's call one of the three dimensions of the state space `u`. For a fixed `u.min()`, `u.max()`, if I increase the grid size enough, I can usually invert `A`. For the order of magnitudes: If the transition rate *across grid points* is around 100, inverting `A` fails. When it's only around `10`, it works.

Now, I can't always throw more grid points at the problem. Also, I'm not sure of the fundamental problem behind why the grid size matters where. Could anyone shed some light on what's happening here, and whether there's an alternative way forward?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that there was some floating point error. The key insight to get around this was that the stationary distribution is invariant to the speed of convergence.

So then I just rescaled `A2 = A/x`, for `x > 0`. Depending which way the floating point errors went, `x` was either above or below `1`. Inverting `A2` was then possible without problems.